# What does a negative terminal growth rate mean?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation, price

Say I truly believe in efficient markets (prices reflect all available information to investors). Under this condition, say I figured that a company has a growth rate that is negative perpetually.

Intuitively, what does a negative terminal growth rate imply? Is it at all realistic?

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, it means that the company is expected to have a finite lifespan, perhaps because it makes a product that is becoming highly unpopular or obsolete.

While this is of course not as lucrative as a company with positive growth prospects, there is no inconsistency in valuing or investing in such a company. The valuation will readily converge and have less uncertainty.

Since there is no need to reinvest profits to expand, the company is likely to pay a high dividend yield. The stock can deliver a positive return if this yield outweighs the negative growth rate.

Here is a [related answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/30150/19618).